# SkiaSharp converting SVG to PNG spoils image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, skiasharp

After my method converts SVG code to PNG, it draw lines inside of square. Originally they were just square borders.

```
private void svgToPng(int itemId)
{
    // Load created svg file
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("...\\lastCreated.svg");

    XmlReader svgSrc = new XmlNodeReader(doc);

    string svgSaveAs = "...\\lastCreated.png";
    var quality = 100;

    var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
    var pict = svg.Load(svgSrc);

    var dimen = new SkiaSharp.SKSizeI
    (
         (int) Math.Ceiling(pict.CullRect.Width),
         (int) Math.Ceiling(pict.CullRect.Height)
    );
    var matrix = SKMatrix.MakeScale(1, 1);
    var img = SKImage.FromPicture(pict, dimen, matrix);

    // Convert to PNG
    var skdata = img.Encode(SkiaSharp.SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, quality);

    using(var stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(svgSaveAs))
    {
         skdata.SaveTo(stream);
    }

    // Upload image
    uploadImage("...\\lastCreated.png", itemId);
}
```

Here is pictures

**Good:**

[image: Good]

**Bad:**

[image]

The best way is to use Inkscape via Process. Don't even try to use libraries,  all of them have bugs.

Comment: your second link is broken

Comment: please make sure all links you share are working

Comment: @Kevin Please try now.

Comment: @kakabali please try again

Comment: -1 because you haven't done the work to diagnose the bug. The title of this issue includes "PNG" but you haven't identified whether PNG compression, let alone the creation of bitmap images, is the issue. Most probably the issue affects all rendering, whether to files or on-screen, and you haven't ruled that out before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/Svg.Skia

This library is far more complete and supports most of the SVG spec.